# Show exit code on shell prompt always 0, why

Tags: bash

I wish to show exit code on Bash shell prompt, so that I can easily know whether the previous command run successfully, however, it always show 0. Anything wrong with this? Then is it possible to accomplish the desired result?

```
 PS1="\t <\w> ERR:$(echo $?) \$ "
```

[image]

-- Bash 4.1.10 on openSUSE 11.4

Comment: What are the thingamajigs left of the control box ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `$` in order to inhibit expansion when the assignment is executed.

```
PS1="\t <\w> ERR:$(echo \$?) \$ "
```

​

```
22:04:48 <~/Work/tmp> ERR:x $ true
22:05:51 <~/Work/tmp> ERR:0 $ false
22:05:52 <~/Work/tmp> ERR:1 $
```